# Exim after Thunderbird update: "Could not negotiate a supported cipher suite"

Tags: ssl, exim, thunderbird, starttls, gnutls

Recently, after I installed updates on my Kubuntu 14.04. system and a **new version of thunderbird** was installed, **I could not send emails any more**. It prompts:

> Sending of message failed. The message could not be sent because the
>   connection to SMTP server [..] was lost in the middle of the
>   transaction. Try again or contact your network administrator.

Since I am the administrator of my mail server (exim) I checked the logs. Everytime I try to send an email with thunberbird it says:

> TLS error on connection from [..] (gnutls_handshake): **Could not negotiate a supported cipher suite.**

That's odd. How could that happen out of the blue? I googled the problem, but other people with this message in the logs had something wrong with their certificate installation (too new algorithm or the like). But I did not change anything with my certificate and additionally it is still no problem to send mails with K-9 Mail from my android phone (which has the same TLS settings).

My Server runs **Debian 7.6** with **EXIM 4.80**.

(In case it matters: My certificates are signed by CACert).

For now I downgraded thunderbird (`sudo apt-get install thunderbird=1:24.4.0+build1-0ubuntu1`). This worked, but is of course no permanent solution.

What is wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: What ciphers do you have enabled on server-side? It the default ones, what are these defaults in your setup? Ans which one is the "new version of Thunderbird" that does not work?

Comment: @sebix: It's the defaults. How do I figure out what the defaults are? The "new" version is 31.

Comment: Have you updated the _server_ and checked the cipher suites in your exim configuration?

Comment: @MichaelHampton: I did not configure any cipher suites in my exim config, hoping that the guys that develop exim/gnutls have a better understanding of ssl than I do and choose good default. I could not figure out how to check what the defaults actually are. I did not update the server after updating thunderbird. However I made sure that I am running the most recent version from the debian repo.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have no idea what the problem was, but it must have to do with my certificates after all. I just regenerated the certificates, again using the [CSR script from CACert](http://svn.cacert.org/CAcert/Software/CSRGenerator/csr). To my knowledge I did not do anything different than the last time I generated my certificates. But with my fresh certificates everything works like a charm again.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox and Thunderbird 31 removed support for weak cipher suites, therefore you are getting this error.

You need to update your server's SSL configuration according to this [Mozilla wiki article](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Server_Side_TLS).

A quote of the recommended backward compatible cipher suite string:

- Ciphersuite: ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128:AES256:AES:DES-CBC3-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK
- Versions: SSLv3, TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2
- RSA key size: 2048
- DH Parameter size: 1024
- Elliptic curves: secp256r1, secp384r1, secp521r1

You should be able to specify the ciphers with `tls_require_ciphers` directive. It should accept the Ciphersuite string from above.

Comment: How do I configure those with exim4 and GNU TLS? I figured that there is the `tls_require_ciphers` option in exim, but the manual says that it is just a "priority string" and that sounds like I just set which ciphers are preferred but not which are supported.

Comment: See updated answer.

Comment: Isn't GnuTLS prioritizing secure ciphers by default?

Comment: @TeroKilkanen: I tried that, but I get the following error (I shortend it): `tls_require_ciphers invalid: gnutls_priority_init(ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:[..]:!MD5:!PSK) failed at offset 0, "ECDHE-RS.." failed: The request is invalid.`

Answer (score 1):

As you cam read here http://kb.mozillazine.org/Security.tls.version.*, Thunderbird with `Security.tls.version.max` set to 2 or 3 will not fallback to lower settings.

Even if you configure Exim 4.80 with the `tls_require_ciphers` as mentioned above, it will not offer ECDHE at first place (at least that's what I've read somewhere so believe this with care). Maybe this also is a certificate issue and renewing it with different settings could help, too.

So to have Thunderbird behave as before go the the configuration editor (Preferences -> Advanced -> Config Editor (Button) ) and search for `tls` then change `security.tls.version.max` to 1 and it should work again.