# exim4 gnu_tls cipher configuration for incoming connections to gmail

Tags: exim, gmail, ssl, gnutls

On the Debian 7 / exim4 / gnutls mailserver I'm running, since about 1-2 weeks, mails from gmail don't arrive any more with the following typical error message in the log file:

```
2015-02-14 17:32:07 TLS error on connection from mail-la0-f52.google.com [209.85.215.52] (gnutls_handshake): Could not negotiate a supported cipher suite.
```

Does anyone know if google changed anything in their configuration?

What is your recommended settings for `tls_require_ciphers` in the exim4 configuration?

This problem appeared out of blue sky, I did no certificate change or relevant updates in the last two weeks. Am I the only one with this problem?

Answer (score 3):

**The problem was:** The server certificate was signed with a SHA-512 hash. Debian 7 still comes with `gnutls` 2.x, but `gnutls` 3.x is required to savely use SHA-512 signed certificates. I was installing this certificate on Dec 23, 2014.

Google seems to have altered their policies in cipher negotiation to be more strict on fall back cipher suits and/or signature checking. Until end of Jan 2015, mail exchange with gmail servers worked (with the Debian 7 + gnutls 2.6 + SHA-512 signed CRT configuration), then it suddenly dropped, so no emails could be received from gmail after end of January 2015 without changes on my side.

**Solution:** Substituting for an SHA-256 signed Certificate or upgrading to `gnutls` 3.x (which is currently not in the stable branch of Debian 7) solves the problem. (I did the first.)

**Note 1:** Researching online I found out that this is also a problem of many non-commertial **CaCert.org** certificates which are SHA-512 signed by default now. It seems that CaCert.org now provides an "advanced option" in the CRT generation interface to select SHA-256 to avoid this problem for Debian 7 users. However, on this precise issue there is currently a lot of misleading hints and suggestions in online forums, saying that the `tls_require_ciphers` variable must be set properly in the `exim4` configuation to ensure proper cipher suite negotiation. This is wrong; I did not adjust this variable at all.

**Note 2:** There is a related problem concerning customers using **Thunderbird** connecting to an `exim4` + Debian 7 MTA for sending mail (see this post: [Exim after Thunderbird update: "Could not negotiate a supported cipher suite"](https://serverfault.com/questions/615855/exim-after-thunderbird-update-could-not-negotiate-a-supported-cipher-suite?rq=1) , which was closed but is in fact highly related.) 
Thunderbird has exactly the same strict configuration as gmail uses when negotiatin cipher suite, so it fails in this particular circumstances when the server uses `gnutls` < 3.x but an SHA-512 signed CRT. The solution is the same: Use a SHA-256 signed CRT or update libgnutls (if possible in your distribution).